# How to get row values as columns using Sql Query CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, case-when

I have a table

```
s_id   student_name attendance_date status
1        student1     2020-01-01     P
2        student1     2020-01-02     P
3        student2     2020-01-01     P
4        student2     2020-01-02     A
```

I want my table as

```
s_id    student_name   01-01-2020   02-01-2020
1       student1       P             P
2       student2       P             A
```

I have tried using CASE WHEN statement but students names are keep repeating. How can i get the result without repeating the names of student?

Comment: If someone later adds a new row with the date 2020-04-23, do you want a new column suddenly?

Comment: Using php i have used filter for date. user can enter a date by his choice.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: id seems to have no meaning in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pivot over a fixed list of dates, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    s_id, 
    student_name,
    max(case when attendance_date = '2020-01-01' then status end) `2020-01-01`,
    max(case when attendance_date = '2020-01-02' then status end) `2020-01-02`
from mytable
group by s_id, student_name
order by s_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following, here is the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g2VjMKBfKCVeDQP5cK2m4G/0). I have not included `s_id` as it does not make any sense here to include it.

```
select
    student_name,
    max(case when attendance_date='2020-01-01' then status end) as '01-01-2020',
    max(case when attendance_date='2020-01-02' then status end) as '01-02-2020'
from yourTable
group by
    student_name
```

Comment: Without a `group by` clause, this is not a valid query.

Comment: thank you so much for your responds. it showing sql error:Invalid use of group function